# Mocking a dynamically-generated class in ruby metaprogramming with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, metaprogramming

I'm new to TDD *and* metaprogramming so bear with me!

I have a Reporter class (to wrap the Garb ruby gem) that will generate a new report class on-the-fly and assign it to a GoogleAnalyticsReport module when I hit method_missing. The main gist is as follows:

```rb
# Reporter.rb 
def initialize(profile)
  @profile = profile
end

def method_missing(method, *args)       
  method_name = method.to_s
  super unless valid_method_name?(method_name)

  class_name = build_class_name(method_name)
  klass = existing_report_class(class_name) || 
    build_new_report_class(method_name, class_name)
  klass.results(@profile)
end

def build_new_report_class(method_name, class_name)
  klass = GoogleAnalyticsReports.const_set(class_name, Class.new)
  klass.extend Garb::Model
  klass.metrics << metrics(method_name)
  klass.dimensions << dimensions(method_name)
  return klass
end
```

The type of 'profile' that the Reporter expects is a Garb::Management::Profile.

In order to test some of my private methods on this Reporter class (such as valid_method_name? or build_class_name), I believe I want to mock the profile with rspec as it's not a detail that I'm interested in.

However, the call to klass.**results**(@profile) - is executing and killing me, so I haven't stubbed the Garb::Model that I'm extending in my meta part.

Here's how I'm mocking and stubbing so far... the spec implementation is of course not important:

```rb
describe GoogleAnalyticsReports::Reporter do
  before do
    @mock_model = mock('Garb::Model')
    @mock_model.stub(:results) # doesn't work!

    @mock_profile = mock('Garb::Management::Profile')
    @mock_profile.stub!(:session)

    @reporter = GoogleAnalyticsReports::Reporter.new(@mock_profile)
  end

  describe 'valid_method_name' do
    it 'should not allow bla' do
      @reporter.valid_method_name?('bla').should be_false
    end
  end
end
```

Does anyone know how I can stub the call to the ***results*** method on my newly created class?

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

~ Stu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
@mock_model = mock('Garb::Model')
@mock_model.stub(:results) # doesn't work!
```

I think you want to do:

```
Garb::Model.any_instance.stub(:results)
```

This will stub out any instance of Garb::Model to return results. You need to do this because you are not actually passing @mock_model into any class/method that will use it so you have to be a bit more general.

Comment: My project was rails 2.3 so I had to pull my class out into a new gem to free myself of the web pf dependencies when upgrading rspec mocks. I still have a problem though... we're trying to stub any instance of Garb::Model, which is actually a Module, not a Class. Rspec gives me:

Failure/Error: Garb::Model.any_instance.stub(:results)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `any_instance' for Garb::Model:Module

Any ideas how to mock any instance of a class that extends a module??

Cheers

Comment: I think you need rspec 2.6 or greater to get any_instance support. In terms of stubbing modules this is not possible as far as I am aware - apart from when the method is defined on the eingen class for the module (def self.hello_world). If you do not know the instance that you want to stub then I think you are probably going down the wrong route with your tests..

Comment: Agreed Derek - I think I'm getting tangled up because my code isn't correct (read: testable) enough. Thanks for your answers.

For anyone reading and interested, I ended up using VCR and fakeweb to stub out the http stuff that Garb required. See my implementation here: https://github.com/stuliston/garb-reporter/blob/master/spec/garb_reporter_spec.rb